# Checking subclass of base class object - inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-inference

I need to know at execution-time the subtype of the base-class object I'm working with.

First of all I have my base-class called `Element`. Then, I have several subclasses called `Car`, `Adult`... all derived from `Element`. In some part of my code I create some objets of that types which I store in an `Element` array.

The problem comes when I get through the array and I try to recover the object's primary type.

I've been trying to do so using `dynamic_cast` but every `Element` can be cast successfully to `Car`, `Adult`, or whatever ...

This is the code:

```
Element elements[3];
Car c;
Adult a1;
Adult a2;
elements[0] = c;
elements[1] = a1;
elements[2] = a2;
int numElements = 3;
for(int i = 0; i< numElements; i++){
    if(dynamic_cast<Adult*>(&elements[i]) == nullptr){
        cout << "Its an adult" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Sth else" << endl;
    }
}
```

And that's the result:

```
Its an adult
Its an adult
Its an adult
```

This is the subclasses code:

```
class Car : public Element{
    ...
};

class Adult : public Element{
    ...
};
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] demonstrating how you're creating the objects, how you're filling the array, how you cast the objects, and how the casts succeed.

Comment: Sounds like you want either [is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) or [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I've tried both of them but they both say Its an adult when there's one is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

**One**, `Element elements[3];` creates an array of `Element` objects. Not of "objects of classes derived from `Element`". You cannot store anything other than an `Element` in such an array, and any attempt to do so results in [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/1782465): the non-`Element` part of the source object is sliced away (discarded) and only the `Element` part makes it in.

If you want dynamic polymorphism, you have to use pointers or references, and usually also dynamic allocation. In your case, this could look something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Element> elements[3];
Car c;
Adult a1;
Adult a2;
elements[0] = std::make_unique<Car>(c);
elements[1] = std::make_unique<Adult>(a1);
elements[2] = std::make_uniuqe<Adult>(a2);
```

Or, if you want to avoid copying the objects:

```
std::unique_ptr<Element> elements[3];
auto c = std::make_unique<Car>();
auto a1 = std::make_unique<Adult>();
auto a2 = std::make_unique<Adult>();
elements[0] = std::move(c);
elements[1] = std::move(a1);
elements[2] = std::move(a2);
```

Or just create them directly in the array:

```
std::unique_ptr<Element> elements[3];
elements[0] = std::make_unique<Car>();
elements[1] = std::make_unique<Adult>();
elements[2] = std::make_unique<Adult>();
```

**Two**, you're misinterpreting the result of `dynamic_cast`. If `dynamic_cast` succeeds, it returns the pointer cast to the appropriate type. If it fails, it returns a null pointer. Your condition is reversed, as you're interpreting `== nullptr` as a success. The loop should actually look like this (with the `unique_ptr`s from point #1 in place):

```
for(int i = 0; i< numElements; i++){
    if(dynamic_cast<Adult*>(elements[i].get())){
        cout << "Its an adult" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Sth else" << endl;
    }
}
```

---

A few side notes:

- Since your `Element` is used as a polymorphic base class, it should have a virtual destructor. Otherwise, using a pointer of type `Element` to delete a dynamically allocated object of a type derived from `Element` will result in Undefined Behaviour (most likely memory corruption).
- If your `Element` is intended only as an abstract base and you never expect objects of type exactly `Element` (not derived from it) to exist, you should make `Element` abstract by giving it at least one pure virtual function (`virtual void foo() = 0;`). If it's a real base class, it will probably naturally contain a few candidates for that.
- Needing to know the exact derived type when working with a base class is often a sign of bad design. Ideally, `Element` should contain virtual functions covering all functionality you may need to do with the objects in a type-abstracted manner. Exceptions exist, of course, but you should probably re-evaluate your design to make sure those `dynamic_casts` are actually necessary.